# HTML Table merge layout

Tags: html, html-table

What I'm trying to get:

```
+---------+---------------------------+--------------+
|         |                           |              |
+---------+                           |              |
|         |                           |              |
|         +-----------------+---------+              |
|         |                 |         |              |
|         +-----------------+         |              |
|         |                 |         |              |
|         +-----------------+         |              |
|         |                 |         |              |
+---------+-----------------+---------+              |
|         |                 |         |              |
+---------+-----------------+---------+--------------+
```

The HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td rowspan="2" colspan="2"></td>
        <td rowspan="6"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="4"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td rowspan="3"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

But This is not working. I'm not able to merge the second column of first row in 2*2 cells. It always becomes `colspan="2"` only. The `rowspan="2"` is not working. I tried making this using HTML table generator sites like http://html-tables.com/ but it doesn't works there too.

This is what I'm getting:

```
+---------+---------------------------+--------------+
|         |                           |              |
+---------+-----------------+---------+              |
|         |                 |         |              |
|         +-----------------+         |              |
|         |                 |         |              |
|         +-----------------+         |              |
|         |                 |         |              |
+---------+-----------------+---------+              |
|         |                 |         |              |
+---------+-----------------+---------+--------------+
```

What I think is this is not possible in HTML as it is not working anywhere? Is there any way to achieve the result I want? As shown on the drawing.

Comment: Is this for layout? Don’t use tables for layout. For this very reason.

Comment: This is not for layout. I need to show some data, and I need to put multiple tables on a single page. It is something like 1 table for 1 products. Though I can do this by css but I just saw this this problem and can't figure out what I should do. So I'm here to know..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your graphic presentation has six rows, but the table has only five `tr` elements. To fix this, duplicate the fourth `tr` element,

```
  <tr>
      <td></td>
  </tr>
```

Even after this fix, the table does not look right, but that’s because it has no real content. There is nothing that requires the second row to have positive height. Add some multi-line content to the second `td` element, and you’ll see that it makes the second row gain height.

Comment: Yes that is true. If I add content the second cell gains height, but it is doesn't unless I have enough content. I wanted the second cell to have more height than the first cell. Seems this isn't possible by default.

Comment: You can set a minimum height on a table row, e.g. `tr { height: 2em }`.

Answer (score 0):

check that number of columns and rows of the table do not mismatch. inside a div element you can create a html table as given below:

```
<div>
    <table border="1" width="50%" cellspacing="10" cellpadding="10">
        <tr>
            <td style="width:60px"></td>
            <td></td>
            <td rowspan="3"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="height:50px">
            <td colspan="2">
                <table border="1" width="100%" cellspacing="10" cellpadding="10">
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>
                            <table width="100%"  cellpadding="10" cellspacing="10" border="1">
                                <tr>
                                    <td></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td></td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                <table border="1" width="100%" cellspacing="10" cellpadding="10">
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```